# unix file utility: magic syntax

Tags: file, unix, mime

I would like to create a custom `magic` file for the `file` utility, but I'm having a really hard time understanding the syntax described in `man magic`.

I need to test several places, each of which can contain several strings. Only if all the tests succeed would it print a file type.

To summarize, I would like a test similar to this if it were fields in an SQL database:

```sql
( byte_0 = "A" OR byte_0 = "B" OR byte_0 = "C" )
AND
( byte_1_to_3 = "DEF" OR byte_1_to_3 = "GHI" OR byte_1_to_3 = "JKL" )
```

Or in Perl regexp syntax:

```perl
m/^
  [ABC]
  (DEF|GHI|JKL)
/x
```

Answer (score 1):

`file` has its own syntax, with hundreds of examples.  If the documentation is unclear, you should start by reading examples which are close to your intended changes.  That's what I did with ncurses for example, in the [`terminfo` magic-file](https://github.com/file/file/blob/master/magic/Magdir/terminfo), to describe the Solaris xcurses header as a sequence of strings:

```
    # Rather than SVr4, Solaris "xcurses" writes this header:
    0   regex       \^MAX=[0-9]+,[0-9]+$
    >1  regex       \^BEG=[0-9]+,[0-9]+$
    >2  regex       \^SCROLL=[0-9]+,[0-9]+$
    >3  regex       \^VMIN=[0-9]+$
    >4  regex       \^VTIME=[0-9]+$
    >5  regex       \^FLAGS=0x[[:xdigit:]]+$
    >6  regex       \^FG=[0-9],[0-9]+$
    >7  regex       \^BG=[0-9]+,[0-9]+, Solaris xcurses screen image
    #
```

but without the insight gained by reading this example,

```
    0   string      \032\001
    # 5th character of terminal name list, but not Targa image pixel size (15 16 24 32)
    >16 ubyte       >32
    # namelist, if more than 1 separated by "|" like "st|stterm| simpleterm 0.4.1"
    >>12 regex \^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9.][^|]* Compiled terminfo entry "%-s"
```

the manual page was not (as you report) clear enough that `file` processes a numbered series of steps in sequence.